# Strange arithmetic result

Tags: python, r

:

```
0.3-0.2-0.1 = -2.775558e-17 # in R3.4 / Python 3.5
```

While

```
0.4-0.2-0.1-0.1 = 0.
```

I am very confused now. I am aware of different storage types in both language.
I came on this issue because, I needed to determine if a numeric variable (as a result of different arithmetic operations) is positive or negative.

I need to figure out a reliable way to check the sign of numeric variable.

Comment: Here your values both are neither positive nor negative, what do you want to return in such cases?

Comment: Try using the **Decimal** class:

    >>> from decimal import Decimal
    >>> float(Decimal("0.3") - Decimal("0.2") - Decimal("0.1"))
    0.0

Comment: If you need to have an answer about this "I need to figure out a reliable way to check the sign of numeric variable." then you should probably ask a question about this specific point.

Comment: I usually define a very small constant `epsilon = 0.000000001` and then say that if `x - epsilon < 0` then x is negative, and if `x + epsilon > 0` then x is positive.